# c-x-f in sr-speedbar mode always splits the main Emacs window; how to stop this?

Tags: elisp

I encounter a problem when using sr-speedbar mode in Emacs. c-x-f or godef-jump (maybe some actions like these two) doesn't open the buffer in the main window, but split the window.

So is there a variable to control this manner? How to force them in the main window?